# What is the difference between Mapper.ProjectTo and Mapper.Map in Asp.net MVC core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

When can we use  **`Mapper.ProjectTo`** over **`Mapper.Map`** in Asp.Net core application? Use of `ProjectTo` method in Entity Framework Core, will it reduce the number of fields I query from the database to match the model if we add it in the beginning of the  `_mapper.ProjectTo` statement? How will it reduces the query number of fields?

Instead of using this

```
_mapper.ProjectTo<CompareVarValdto>(_compareRepo.GetCompareDetailsByid(id))
```

we can use this right?

```
_mapper.Map<CompareVarValdto>(result)
```

`ComapreVarValdto.cs`

```
public class CompareVarValdto
{
    public int CompareVarValId { get; set; }
    public int CURRENT_CATEGORY_ID { get; set; }
    public int Current_LaunguageId { get; set; }
    public int Current_compareDimId { get; set; }
    public string CONTENT { get; set; }
}
```

Controller get method code snippet

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ComapareController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ICompare _compareRepo;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public ComapareController(ICompare compare, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _compareRepo = compare;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult GetComapare(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(_mapper.ProjectTo<CompareVarValdto>(_compareRepo.GetCompareDetailsByid(id)));
            //VS
            //var result = _compareRepo.GetCompareDetailsByid(id);
            //return Ok(_mapper.Map<CompareVarValdto>(result));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                "Error retrieving data from the database");
        }
    }
```

`compareRepo` Database method

```
public IQueryable<CompareDim> GetCompareDetailsByid(int compareId)
{
     return _context.CompareDim.Include("Launguage");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

reference: [automapper LINQ deep dive](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-linq-support-deep-dive/)

I think the article explains your question.
If I understand the article right Mapper.Map works in-memory, Project to creates a expression-tree that needs to be parsed and understood by the underlying query provider.
I'm not sure if it will reduce the number of queried fields. My understanding/guess is, and I hope people will correct me, that ProjectTo is more efficient because the query in only executed after constructing the complete expression tree, and you use the query provider to execute the query (in SQL).

While working in memory: "(...)

> *The main problem people run into here is that typically that source object is some object filled in from a data source, whether it's a
> relational or non-relational source. This implies that the original
> fetch pulled a lot more information back out than we needed to.*"

this does not seem to be the case.